# WSO2 DataService - response: Server connection has failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Using WSO2 DataService Carbon.
[some insert query] -> [insert operation] -> works correctly
[some select query] -> [select operation] -> works correctly ...
But
[some update query] -> [update operation] -> response : "Server connection has failed."

After sent request it i'll take 3-5 min and shows response like this :

Server connection has failed.

Connection test -> 100% Healthy 
Update query works on Oracle SQL Developer well
query input mappings and operation input mappings are correct

Any solution?

Comment: Did you check the database whether values were updated from the WSO2 DSS?

Comment: Does it have any other errors in log file?

Comment: Do you have free space on your hard disk, both DB machine and dss machine?